# How to make an image unclickable inside a html table?

Tags: html

I have an img inside a table row like below. My problem is the image is being clicked and redirecting to a home page but this behavior is seen only in firefox and not IE. How can I avoid the image from being clickable?

Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" width="414" height="231" >
         <img id="pic1" src="" border="0" runat="server" alt="" /><br />
    </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: There's probably an unclosed anchor tag elsewhere on your page. Images do not behave line this by themselves.

Comment: An image shouldn't just link you somewhere automatically. Try turning javascript off on your browser and see if the issue is still happening.

Comment: Its a huge code I suppose I have to figure it out. It works fine in IE though. Thanks guys!

Comment: I got the solution, it was the header height set more than required that caused the problem. Anyways, its done and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" width="414" height="231" >
             <img id="pic1" src="" border="0" runat="server" alt="" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You forgot to close the table tag :D